# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.(asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

> Line 733:        } Line 734: Line 735:        private static bool
>   mAppDebug =
>   WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppDebug"].ToLower().Contains("true");
>   Line 736:        public static bool AppDebug Line 737:        {
>
> Source File: T:\MyProject\IMI03\Helper\IMISecurity.cs    Line: 735
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    IMI03.Helper.IMIApplication..cctor() in
>   T:\MyProject\IMI03\Helper\IMISecurity.cs:735
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'IMI03.Helper.IMIApplication' threw an exception.]
>   IMI03.Helper.IMIApplication.set_PasswordDay(Int32 value) in
>   T:\MyProject\IMI03\Helper\IMISecurity.cs:683
>   IMI03.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   T:\MyProject\IMI03\Global.asax.cs:52

Couldn't  find the erro... what kind of error and how to recitfy it...please??

Answer (score 1):

The `"AppDebug"` setting likely doesn't exist, so calling `ToLower()` on it is throwing a `NullReferenceException`. Make sure you've spelled everything correctly and that the setting is actually there.